# How does UPnP know which IGD to port forward on if there is more than one IGD?

Tags: routing, gateway, vlan, upnp, multicast

Say I have two IGDs on the same subnet with UPnP enabled. The host is configured to use one as its default gateway. How do UPnP applications know which IGD to port forward on. I don't think they use the default gateway configured on the computer to figure that out.

To make things more complex: What if there is another InterVLAN router between the host and IGDs and the InterVLAN router forwards the UPnP packets to the IGDs' VLANs using multicast routing?

Comment: Why don't you think they use the default gateway to figure that out?

Comment: Because every description of UPnP IGD I've found indicates that it uses SSDP even for IGD.

Comment: This tool prompts you to choose an IGD if more than one is found: http://upnp-portmapper.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Locutus were you able to find an answer to this question?

Comment: @user3490458 The behaviour is client application dependent.

Comment: @Locutus Do you have any idea how miniUPNP does it (using 'upnpc -a' command)?